# How can I reduce the height of shiny input widgets?

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny dashboard app, I want to put several (>5) slider inputs inside a box that has a specific height. The height argument in box() only seems to control the height of the box itself, and the contents (sliders) spill out below the box. How can I make the sliders smaller so that they will all fit inside the box? ( I have other things to fit in the page). Heres my example ui:

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
      box(title="inputs",height="200px",
          sliderInput("in1","1",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in2","2",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in3","3",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in4","4",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in5","5",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in6","6",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0),
          sliderInput("in7","7",min = 0,max = 1, step=0.01,value = 0)
      )
  )))
```

Making all the labels NULL helps a bit, but ideally I could have more control over the size/height (and have labels).

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `?sliderInput` has a `width` argument; have you tried changing it?

Comment: I want to change the height, not the width. There is no height argument.

Comment: Ah yes. You may have to look into adapting the [underlying html code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/5Xisp6zQrH0)?

Answer (score 20):

I've discovered that the height of a widget can be changed by putting it inside a div() and setting the height there:

```
div(style="height: 27px;",
        sliderInput("in1",NULL,min = 0,max = 1, step=0.05,value = 0,ticks=F))
```

It seems it should also be possible (and more efficient?) to do this with tags, e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/3m7cq96mcBY/OEICaO_7Na0J, but I can't make that work.

Comment: Now I'd like to find a way to label the sliders on the side and to remove the min / max labels, so I get a simple stack of numbered sliders (with no other labels). But I suspect that will require a customized slider function?

Comment: doesn't work for selectInput (drop-down list), in that case see accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531435/shiny-change-the-size-padding-of-dropdown-menu-select-tags-smaller