# Shiny - change the size (padding?) of dropdown menu (select tags) smaller

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

How can I change the size of dropdown menu (select tags) smaller? I thought it is the padding that makes the dropdown looking 'thick'. So I change the padding to 0 to make it 'thin' and obviously that does not work,

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    # Change the font size.
    tags$style(type='text/css', " .selectize-input, .selectize-dropdown { padding:0 ; }"),

    # Species/ pollutant options
    selectInput(
        inputId = "species",
        label = "Species:",
        choices = c(...)
        ),
   ....
```

The result is quite awkward,

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no cross-browser solution to style most form elements, amongst them `<select>`, `<input type="radio" />` und `<input type="checkbox" />` using CSS only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the dropdown options, it's `line-height` that you want (the padding is already 0 by default I think, look at the CSS on it using the chrome debugger).

For the box itself, it looks like bootstrap is placing a `min-height` on it, so you also need to add `min-height: 0;`.  Again, I just figured this out right now with the debugger by looking at its CSS.

So here's a working solution:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { padding: 2px; min-height: 0;} .selectize-dropdown { line-height: 10px; }"),
    selectInput("test","Test", 1:5)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

Please try to post complete code samples rather than a snippet of code that we have to complete ourselves. Makes it easier and faster for us to try to answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! `Please try to post complete code samples rather than a snippet of code that we have to complete ourselves. Makes it easier and faster for us to try to answer` - will keep that in mind next time. Thank you.

Comment: providing screenshots of the debugger would significantly enhance this already correct answer.